# Merge and synonymize [bookmark] with [bookmarks]

Tags: feature-request, status-completed, tags, meta, synonym-request

The tag [bookmark](/questions/tagged/bookmark) has no wiki or excerpt.  It has 12 questions, and quite a few, if not all of those questions seem to be asking about the SE bookmarks - and there is already a much clearer, better tag for that:  [bookmarks](/questions/tagged/bookmarks).  Can we please synonymize (or outright burn) [bookmark](/questions/tagged/bookmark) with [bookmarks](/questions/tagged/bookmarks) (I don't have 5 score in the tag to suggest a synonym)?

Comment: I checked the synonym list, and it's not there.

Comment: Synonym suggested

Comment: I don't see it pending @Glorfindel

Comment: @Luuklag no? https://meta.stackexchange.com/tags/synonyms?tab=Newest&filter=Suggested – that table shows the active ('approved') ones by default

Comment: @Glorfindel guess it restricts it from view as I don't have the required tag score.

Comment: @Luuklag Glorfindel & Ollie, You [can see](https://i.stack.imgur.com/L1XUy.png) it here: https://meta.stackexchange.com/tags/bookmarks/synonyms - even without privilege to vote.

Comment: This [was completed](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6ySHG.png) at some point in the meantime.